# How can i compile multi module project without aggregator?

Tags: java, spring, maven, build, build-process

How can i compile multi module project, from main module with dependencies without aggregator
Structure is:

```
Root
|-core
    |-src
    |-pom.xml
|-model
    |-src
    |-pom.xml
|-services
    |-src
    |-pom.xml
|-api
    |-src
    |-pom.xml
```

Content of api/pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>services</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
 ...
 </dependencies>
```

Command:

```
root/api> mvn package
```

Error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.example:services:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT,...
```

But with aggregator works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>aggregators</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>api-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Compiler: API</name>

    <modules>
        <module>../../model</module>
        <module>../../core</module>
        <module>../../services</module>
        <module>../../api</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Can i build project without aggregator, may by by ussing plugins such as "maven-assembly-plugin"?
Or how i can use spring-boot:run in multi module structure
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot. How else will Maven know to build services module? You can build every module manually one after the other, however it's not recommended. Why you don't want to use an aggregator?

Comment: I want to use command "mvn spring-boot:run" that can be applied only for one module, and it doesn't works with aggregators

Comment: Build the entire code by running "mvn install" from the aggregator and then run "mvn spring-boot:run"

Comment: another option is (adding to Koby's comment): create a profile `run-springboot` which binds `spring-boot:run` to a late phase (say: `verify`) only in your api module. Then you can do everything together runnint `mvn clean install -Prun-springboot` from the aggegrator module.

Comment: And please: put the aggegrator where it belongs, into the root.